# What does そこまでのもの mean here?

Tags: meaning

> 【ノーシン】「いえ、別に教会運営によるものではないのです」
>   【アスタ】「ん？　じゃあ、どうして？」
>   【サイレント】「ぶっちゃけ、解読された内容を読んだ教皇はショックを受けて、びびっています。単にへたれているだけですね」
>   【ノーシン】「お恥ずかしながら、その通りです」
>   【アスタ】「相変わらずサイレントさん容赦ないな」
>   【ノーシン】「あまりに衝撃的なので、まだ各国の王にもお話ししておりません……」
>   【ラミアス】「では、なぜアスタにだけ話すのだ？」
>   【サイレント】「それは……アスタさんが蛇紋の総帥――　前教皇のセーデスと戦う決意をなさっているからです」
>   【キャスリン】「**そこまでのものなのか**……」

My question is to what キャスリン is commenting on. To me, it looks like she could be talking about the reason for telling アスタ the truth before the kings (i.e. is being prepared to fight 蛇紋の総帥 reason enough for him to be told before the kings of all the countries), or is it that what has been discovered is so shocking that at the moment they have decided that it is only necessary for アスタ to know (as what he will have to deal with is directly related to the content of what has been discovered).

Comment: It's still ambiguous if it's referring to the issue being serious or アスタ being worth relying, and if the tone is impressive or doubtful.

Comment: I've noticed some more answers and comments recently, so if anyone else cares I'll add some more info. Based on what I remember, her facial expression was one of doubt and skepticism. She would think that アスタ  is not the most reliable guy around. but one you can count on in the end. If it's not already clear, she is part of his party. Also, only 
サイレント and ノーシン have read the 解読された内容 and everyone else is told it shortly after.

Answer (score 2):

I think そこまでのもの means that the decoded context is very shocking insomuch that ノーシン goes as far as telling them to アスタ, who has decided to fight against the previous pope セーデス.

Comment: Although I think I understand the gist of your answer, "decoded context" is an interesting choice of wording.  Would you be willing to give a Japanese version and/or further explanation of what you meant by "decoded context" in the comments?

Comment: I translated 解読された内容 as decoded context. And does the phrase "ノーシン tells them to アスタ who has decided" make sense?

Comment: Okay, I was guessing you meant something like that but wanted to make sure I understood your intended nuance correctly.  We actually want "contents" for 内容 (I don't know how to translate "context" but it is almost like "background" ~ 会話の背景?).  I suggest "... means that the contents of the conversation were very shocking to キャスリン insomuch ...".  This might be a smoother way to convey your intended meaning.  The rest of the sentence made sense, but it did have some minor grammatical issues (I proposed an edit for those).

Comment: Some brief notes on the edit: Usually "Alice tells Bob to __" is used for orders, eg "Alice told Bob to clean his room".  In this case it was clear that that was not your intent, so the sentence still made sense, but using "to" sounds funny here.  For giving information, you can use "Alice tells Bob that __" or even just "Alice tells Bob ___" ("that" =と here).   The "who" looks like you're trying to make a subordinate clause, but that isn't ideal here.  [X] = "アスタ has decided to fight ..." (information) => "アスタ tells them (that) [X]".  Please let me know if you'd like more details.

Comment: 編集後は「ノーシンは『アスタがセーデスと戦う決心をした』ということを人々に話す」になっていますが、もともとはたぶん「ノーシンは、セーデスと戦う決心をしたアスタに(だけ？)、解読された内容を話す」って言いたかったんですよね・・・

Comment: @WeirdlyCheezy I want to say "ノーシンは、セーデスと戦う決心をしたアスタに伝えるほど" as chocolate-san said. Is my sentence wrong and how do I say this in English?

Comment: 今更気づいてごめん、もっと早くもう一回よんでよかったのに、「理解された内容」はもとの引用と同じでしたね。その場合に「ノーシン's understanding of the contents (of the book)」とか「what he (ノーシン) knows about the contents (of the book)」と言えます。chocolateさんが書いてくれての２つ目の文章は直接通訳すれば「ノーシン telling what he knows about the contents of the book (only) to アスタ, who has the will to fight the pope セーデス, (is very shocking to キャスリン)」。この場合に、「アスタだけに話したい」という事はキャスリンに衝撃的だったというニュアンスになると思います。「理解された内容」や「戦う決心」や「アスタだけに話す」など、どの所はキャスリンにとって衝撃的なのか、重要な所だと思いますから、それに対してTamさんはどう思うと確認したいと思います。

Comment: It isn't 理解された内容 but　解読された内容. And I don't know this story, so I can't know the 解読された内容.

Comment: Ah sorry. I would use the same English for 読解 here though: "understanding of"/"knowledge about" (the contents of the book).

Comment: Given all that, I might go with "means that the contents of the book are very shocking insomuch that ノーシン goes as far as telling them to アスタ, who has decided to fight against the previous pope セーデス".
The "goes as far as" adds the 伝えるほど nuance, and the comma after アスタ makes it grammatically clear that there's an intended subjunctive clause.

Comment: @Yuuichi Tam @ WeirdlyCheezy  For what it's worth, I've added a few more pieces of information to a comment on my original post.

Answer (score 0):

ノーシン's secret talk 「あまりに衝撃的なので、まだ各国の王にもお話ししておりません」
キャサリン 「What big secret it is」

ノーシン talks about "something surprising" from now.

Comment: Hi. Perhaps you would like to add more explanation to this answer to link the content of your answer to what the OP asked. As it is now, it just appears to quote a line from the question, and the role of 「what big secret it is」 is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

When we say そこまでのものなのか（？）, it usually means either (1) Is it a so serious (grave) matter?, or (2) Is it just so much (as a light thing)?

I cannot tell which the qouted comment fits because I don't know the story at all. But I think you who are familiar with the story can easily judge which case of the above the phrase in question comes under from the context.